# Raspberry Pi Random Video w/ GPIO Button using Python

Tags: python, random, video, gpio

So I am NOT a Python developer and have cobbled together something that works, but not like I want to. Let me describe what I *want*:

On an antique television, I want the Pi to play consecutive random videos.
IF a button is pressed, I want to change to a new random video, and continue playing random videos unless another button press.

Simply, the Python code should play random videos - and start a different random video if a button is pressed.
After which, more random videos should be played.

For background, I have a wonderfully restored 1946 Philco Predicta television and trying to make it more useful in 2o2o. I have my video folder filled with period-correct videos and commercials... it'll be great when I get my code better.

Heres what I have cobbled up currently. What it does now is... when I boot the system, it plays ONE random video. Then, it plays random videos when a button is pressed. Can anyone help me do this more like what I want?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import random

buttonPin = 21

directory = "/home/pi/Videos/"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN)

def playEpisode():
    episode = random.choice(os.listdir(directory))
    cmd = "nohup omxplayer --aspect-mode stretch "+"'"+directory+episode+"' &"
#    cmd = "nohup omxplayer -o alsa --aspect-mode stretch "+"'"+directory+episode+"' &"
#    the above w/ added -o alsa for bluetooth speakers fails after the first video. because of how i kill omxplayer? or nohup? further investigation needed.
    print('Killing all omxplayer processes . . .')
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    os.system(cmd)

try:

#    os.system('clear')
#added below to see if it will play random UNTIL button press...
    playEpisode()
    print('Waiting for button press . . .')
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(buttonPin, GPIO.FALLING)
    print('[x] Recieved button press.')
    print('Playing random video . . .')
    playEpisode()

    #point to location of this file
    os.system('sudo python /home/pi/predicta.py')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: not entirely clear what the issue is. is the problem that once you press the button more videos dont keep playing? if so you do something as simple as putting your second `playEpisode` into an infinite loop `while True` type deal

Comment: Again, I'm not sure - but I think one of my issues is that I'm using ```GPIO.wait_for_edge(buttonPin, GPIO.FALLING)``` - so the script stops and waits for a button press. I think I need to do a while True (or False) loop and test some different GPIO command to see when the state changes. Am I on the right track with that, anyone? Suggestions appreciated - but I'm getting there. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import os
import random
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

buttonPin = 21
directory = "/home/pi/Videos/"

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout

def playEpisode():
    with suppress_stdout():
        episode = random.choice(os.listdir(directory))
        cmd = "nohup omxplayer --aspect-mode stretch "+"'"+directory+epis$
        os.system('sudo killall omxplayer.bin')
        os.system('sudo killall omxplayer')
        os.system(cmd)

playEpisode()
button = Button(buttonPin)
button.when_released = playEpisode
pause()
```

I updated my code a bit... this one starts a random video at runtime, then will goto a new random video if the button is pressed - and will play a new random video if button is pressed after a random video stops...

But I still want to somehow test for omxplayer running, or stopping - and play another random video if omxplayer stops playing the current one. So long as button presses during all that work, then I'd be really close.

Later, I'd love to add a commercial after every 3rd video - but thats not a need right now.